# StartInfos.argument doesn't execute

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, command-prompt

i want to open the prompt command and execute arguments so i'm using this code :

```html
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
           // startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"cd\";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```

But the arguments doesn't works and the prompt command open on bin/debug folder instead of executing cd\ and open on c:/

tried with :

```html
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"cd\");
```

but didnt work either

(cd\ is just an example to see if it work the final command i need to execute is cd/ cd C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg ffmpeg32 -i C:\Users\Oxitroy\Documents\instaJanvier1.mp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add /c to the command:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", @" /c cd\");
```

/c : Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.

But try something a little more lengthy, so you can see if anything happens.

Comment: You place the /c in the wrong place no?
Wrong path error

Comment: Yes, you are right. I edited the answer, and it runs in linqPad as shown.

Comment: Okay thanks  and how should i manage argument that contains space since  space means the end of an argument?

Comment: It's up to the command receiving the argument. For most commands you can wrap file paths in " ". For instance @" /c cd ""\Program files""".